# Matlab R2012B How to disable Java virtual machine?

Tags: java, matlab, jvm

I need to disable JVM in Matlab R2012B to free memory.I tried the command "-nojvm" at the end of the launch string but it doesn't work...
samobody can help me?

Thanks...

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `-nojvm`, not `-nojmv`.

Comment: lol! I didn't even see that.

Comment: Given the fact that the OP misspelled some words in his/her post, I don't know if `nojmv` was a mistake and that they meant `nojvm`... or if they really meant `nojmv`... anyway, +1.

Comment: yes,it's only a mistake.

Comment: D:\Programmi\MATLAB\R2012b\bin\matlab.exe 'space'-nojvm It was only a space!